# Select text between two words

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I am retrieving some data from the Wiktionary API. Their API parses an entire block of text with no html attributes or xml attributes.

An example of the text:

```
===Etymology===
{{-er|develop}}

===Pronunciation===
* {{a|UK}} {{IPA|/dɪˈvɛləpə(ɹ)/}}
* {{a|US}} {{IPA|/dɪˈvɛləpɚ/}}

===Noun===
{{en-noun}}

# A person or entity engaged in the [[creation]] or [[improvement]] of certain classes of products.
# A [[real estate]] developer; a person or company who prepares a parcel of land for sale, or creates structures on that land.
# A [[film]] developer; a person who uses [[chemical]]s to create [[photograph]]s from photograph negatives.
# A [[liquid]] used in the chemical processing of traditional photos.
# A [[software]] developer; a person or company who creates or modifies [[computer]] software.

====Synonyms====
* {{sense|person or company who writes computer software}} [[programmer]]

====Related terms====
* [[develop]]
* [[development]]
* [[developmental]]
```

Is it possible to **select the text between ===Noun=== and ====Synonyms==== ?**
For example I want to end up with this:

A person or entity engaged in the creation or improvement of certain classes of products.

A real estate developer; a person or company who prepares a parcel of land for sale, or creates structures on that land.

A film developer; a person who uses [[chemical]]s to create [[photograph]]s from photograph negatives.

A liquid used in the chemical processing of traditional photos.

======================

The entire block of text can be found here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5ETx4ivB and the results from the API can be found here in an XML form: http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=developer

Comment: Yes it is possible, what did you try so far in terms of parsing? What does it have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Maybe a Markdown library can help you parse that properly...

Comment: I have tried using Regex in different ways: http://jsfiddle.net/jEQQS. jQuery was tagged not notify devs alike that I wouldnt mind an answer coded with jQuery

Comment: I think you might be confusing stuff about jQuery. jQuery gives you dom manipulation (selecting and adding stuff stuff to the HTML document), cross browser utility methods and abstractization for AJAX. It's not a fit to do with what you're trying to accomplish (string manipulation). I recommend  @ArunPJohny 's answer. It's a lot simpler than a RegExp solution and very straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
var start  = str.indexOf('===Noun==='), end = str.indexOf('====Synonyms====');
var text = str.substring(start + 11, end) // +11 since `indexof` gives the start index and you need to exclude `===Noun===`
```

Comment: Is it possible to select text between two specific words? For example $ Lorem Ipsum $ Joe Doe $ > Select "Lorem Ipsum".

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf() to find the positions of the substrings, then use substr() to get the string between the two positions you find.